# Sync Arduino and Python

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I have some Arduino code that moves motors that I want to sync with a python script to control it using serial.

This is the Arduino code:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

#define P1_STEP_PIN         31
#define P1_DIR_PIN          33
#define P1_ENABLE_PIN       29

#define V1_STEP_PIN         25
#define V1_DIR_PIN          27
#define V1_ENABLE_PIN       23

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int pins[1][2][2] = { 
    { {P1_STEP_PIN, P1_DIR_PIN}, {V1_STEP_PIN, V1_DIR_PIN} }
};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.flush();

  // pins setup
}

void loop()
{
  get_command();
}


void get_command()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    int index = 0;
    delay(100); // let the buffer fill up
    int numChar = Serial.available();

    if ( numChar > ( BUFFER_SIZE - 3 ) ) { //avoid overflow
      numChar = ( BUFFER_SIZE - 3 );
    }

    while (numChar--) {
      buffer[index++] = Serial.read();
    }

    process_command(buffer);
  }
}

void process_command(char* data)
{
  char* parameter;
  parameter = strtok (data, " "); // strtok splits char* in " "

  while (parameter != NULL) {
    long dir, pump, motor, sp, steps;

    switch ( parameter[0] ) {
      // moves the motor around
    }

    parameter = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  for ( int x=0; x < BUFFER_SIZE; x++) {
    buffer[x] = '\0';
  }
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.write("ok");
}
```

The Python part is where I am having problems. The Arduino code works nicely when I send commands from Python to move the motors, but when I send several commands in a row it fails, because I suspect Python sends everything at the same time, not waiting for Arduino to complete each action.

So basically in Python I have tried a bit of everything, mainly stuff like ser.readline() or ser.read(2) and check if the command is "ok".

The strange thing is that there should be an "ok" per command, but there isn't, not all of them arrive to Python. I tried to "flush" it, but its the same.

I created a thread, that listen constantly from serial, and check if the command is "ok", but it is not, maybe if I send 4 commands I receive 2 "ok", sometimes 0, sometimes 1.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simply reading up to 97 bytes (`BUFFER_SIZE - 3`) at a time, try sending an 'end of command' character (or sequence of characters) from the Python code.

In the Arduino sketch read until you receive this 'end of command' sequence and then run the command.